# What are the group objects in the category of finite sets and bijections, and its functor category?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, category-theory, combinatorial-species

> An object $G$ in a category $\mathcal{C}$ is called a group object if, given any object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$, there is a group structure on the morphisms $\operatorname{hom}\left(X,G\right)$ such that $X\mapsto \operatorname{hom}\left(X,G\right)$ is a (contravariant) functor from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\text{Grp}$.

Group objects of the category $\text{Set}$ are groups in the usual sense. Similarly, group objects of the category $\text{FinSet}$ are finite groups.

Assuming that good (non-tautological) descriptions exist,

1. What are the group objects of the category $\text{FinBij}$, the category whose objects are finite sets, and whose morphisms are bijections?
2. What are the group objects of the functor category of $\text{FinBij}$, the category whose objects are functors of $\text{FinBij}$, and whose morphisms are natural transformations?

Comment: So basically the consensus is that while your question is perfectly explicit and well-formulated (and the answer is given in Mariano's answer), what you are considering is not what people usually call group objects in $\mathcal{C}$, but rather representable group objects in the category of presheaves on $\mathcal{C^{op}}$.

Comment: Question 2 is not well-defined. You say the objects are the "functors of $\mathsf{FinBij}$": functors have a domain and a codomain, you only stipulate one of them without saying which one. Do you mean _endofunctors_, that is functors $\mathsf{FinBij} \to \mathsf{FinBij}$ ?

Answer (score 11):

There is no group object: since you only have bijections in your category, for all G there exists an X such that hom(x,G) is empty, so not a group in any way at all.

Comment: By the way, I can also create a definition for which   an empty set is a group and says it is not the "classic" definition.

Comment: You surely can, but the OP didn't in his question. If you ask a question and make explicit such a definition, I would probably have to think more.

Comment: He didn't precise what the definition of group was for him

Comment: Isn't this answer another reason to not call the OP's definition a "group object"?   Bijections of a 1-element set do not constitute a group object (under that definition).

Comment: Why would the set of bijections of a 1-element set not constitute a group?! It is certainly not empty. Not even the set of bijections of a 0-element set is empty!

Comment: Not the set of bijections, the bijections (there is only one of them) used as the structure maps of a group do not count as a "group object". @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez

Comment: @Tsemo, indeed, that is precisely why it is sensible to suppose he is using the standard one. If he *had* made explicit a non-standard definition of group, using the standard one in answering him would be not a great idea.

Comment: Zyx, I am sorry, I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: A 1-element set has a single bijection to itself, which one would use to obtain the structure morphisms for considering that set as a "group object".  But this is apparently forbidden in the OP's definition that requires something about Homs from all the other objects in the category.  @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez

Comment: @TsemoAristide "I can also create a definition for which an empty set is a group" Please do, because I don't see it.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, in the group axioms, replace all reference to the identity element (which may not exist if the group is empty) by "for all x,  x * inverse(x)..." where x is a variable not already in the formula.   Then all axioms are universally quantified and don't care whether the group is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

The question uses a nonstandard definition of group object.

Under the ordinary definition of group object, the answer to the first question is

1. For the identity morphism $1 \to G$ and the multiplication morphism $G \times G \to G$ (if products exist...) to live in a category whose morphisms are *bijections*, $G$ must have cardinality $1$.

The definition in the question is equivalent to the usual only when the category has finite products.  Although your definition would seem to be more general, in a category with terminal object, the subcategory generated by that object has a unique structure of finite products (all of which are equal to the terminal object) and one would therefore expect that the terminal object fits any definition of "group object".  As written in Mariano's answer this is not the case for your definition.  Therefore a different phrase than "group object" should be used for this more general definition.

Comment: This has essentially the same problem as Tsemo's answer.

Comment: The only problem is that this question is using something other than *group object* as the definition of "group object".

Comment: You could argue that his definition is bad or non standard or anything, but he was explicit about what definition he had in mind!

Comment: It's fine to have an explicit (if uncommon) definition, but not to use the standard name for it when consequences of the two definitions are different.

Comment: Oh well. I guess you should report it to overloading police or something! ;-)

Comment: In fact, I think this definition is not that unusual, althought it is usually only considered in contexts where products do exist. It certainly makes sense in general. And it is a good one: how would you define a "topological space object in a category"? A sensible way is to say that it is an object together T with a factorization of hom(-,T) through the forgetful functor from spaces to sets. In this case, it is not clear what the "internal to the category" version of the definition is, if there is any at all!

Comment: If you consider a type of group that has no internal definition I guess it could make sense.

Comment: [It's not something exotic, people do consider it.](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group+object#in_terms_of_presheaves_of_groups) Though the nLab only consider it for a cartesian monoidal category.

Comment: "Cartesian monoidal" is another name for the case where the definition is equivalent to the usual one.   See the edit.  @NajibIdrissi

Comment: Yes, of course. I'm just pointing out that this alternative point of view on group objects exists and wasn't invented by the OP.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez It is not the issue but if you are interested: the _internal version_ of a topological space object uses the notion of sketches. Sketches, introduced by Charles Ehresmann and its school, are a kind of generalized Lawvere theories. If I remember correctly, the sketch for topological spaces was introduced by Albert Burroni.